# jquery modal image with keydown left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to navigate my modal image with keyboard, but i don't know jquery action to change prev and next image, this is my JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.container img').click(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $('.modal').css({
            display: "block"
          });
        $('.modal-content').attr("src", src);
        $(this).keydown(function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 37) { //move left
              //change to prev image  
          } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {  //move right
              //change to next image  
          }
          });
        });
    });
});
```

and my html is :

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt=""/>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <img src="" class="modal-content" alt="">
    </div>
    <img src="img/bg2.jpg" alt=""/>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <img src="" class="modal-content" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

i think i need jquery index to indexing my image, but how perform that?
or there is another method?
Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/akhid1000/w3x5k19m/2/)
thanks

Comment: could you provide jsfiddle for this?

Comment: fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/akhid1000/w3x5k19m/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to bind `keydown event` with `window` and store currently open image object in a global variable.

Try this

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3x5k19m/3/)

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" />
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/287" alt="" />
    </div>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <img src="" class="modal-content" alt="">
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $thisImage;
      $('.container img').click(function() {
        $thisImage = $(this);
        var src = $thisImage.attr('src');
        $('.modal').css({display: "block"});
        $('.modal-content').attr("src", src);    
      });
      $(window).keydown(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 37) { //move left
            if($thisImage.prev().is('img')){
              var prev = $thisImage.prev().attr('src');
              $thisImage = $thisImage.prev();
              $('.modal-content').attr("src", prev);    
            }
          } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 39) { //move right
            if($thisImage.next().is('img')){
              var next = $thisImage.next().attr('src');
              $thisImage = $thisImage.next();
              $('.modal-content').attr("src", next);    
            }  
          }
        });
      $('.close').click(function() {
        $('.modal').css({
          display: "none"
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: thanks Jitendra its work now, i just knew that i need to use prev() and next()